# Cannot vertically center text in secondary NAV bar

Tags: html, css, alignment

On this one particular page, I have added a secondary menu (gray bar) under the primary menu (red bar) to have a few links that, when clicked, will scroll down the page to the correct area.

The secondary menu was, by default, much taller than I wanted it - so by adding a height: 40px; value, I was able to get it to the height I want. The page links, however, stubbornly did not adjust along with the height of the menu and thus, when viewed, they are obviously not in the correct place.

Is there a particular CSS value I can add to try and help this issue? I've tried adjust margin-top, padding-top, vertical-align, etc... and some of that adjusts the gray bar, but absolutely nothing has yet to adjust the text for me.

It doesn't help that I'm using a paid theme I bought rather than one I developed myself (in an attempt to make site management easier for someone else who takes over the site, this is more of a "drag-and-drop" template).

http://www.miltonpreserve.com/about/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added the 40px height to the div with the #aboutmen id. However, some of the content nested in that div has padding that makes it taller than that. If you remove the padding from #menu-about-menu you should see the text become visible. Then (if needed) you can add 'vertical-align: middle' to the elements that you have nested in #menu-about-menu.

Here's a simplified version of what you have going on:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="text">item one</div>
    <div class="text">item two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
outer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

This simplified example has the same problem you're experiencing. If you remove the padding from .inner, you'll see that the problem goes away. Here's a
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/781bf8xa/) with the same code.

Hope that helps!